# Trying to solve a Python looping vowel question

Tags: python, loops, nested

I want to solve the below question:

Input_str - "I love Programming in Python"

Initialise 'n_cnt' as 0 and 'output' as 0
v='aeiouAEIOU'

FOR every w in input_str.split()
Initialise cnt to 0

FOR every c in w
check IF  c is present in v
if true, increment 'cnt' by 1
end inner for loop

check IF 'cnt' is greater than or equal to 'n_cnt'
if true, assign 'cnt' to 'n_cnt' and assign 'w' to 'output'
end outer for loop

Print 'output'

**Here's my code:**

```
Input_str="I love Programming in Python"
n_cnt=0
output=0
v='aeiouAEIOU'
Split=Input_str.split()
for w in Split:
cnt=1
for c in w:
if c in v:
cnt=cnt+1
break
if cnt>=n_cnt:
cnt=n_cnt
output=w
print(output)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste the indented code that one can copy and run.

Comment: Please provide your expected output and error that you are getting while trying to run the problem...Also, you need to consider indentation while writing the code

Comment: "FOR every w in input_str.split() Initialise cnt to 0" but you have `cnt=1`

Answer (score 0):

First, use StackOverflow code editor to create python indentations, so the code can be easily read. Also, try to state your problem clearly, so when someone solves it, you can check that the result is what you want. The following code seems to be the correct version of your source code, it splits the sentence into words and selects the words that contain one character from v.

```
Input_str="I love Programming in zzzz Python"
n_cnt=0
output=0
v='aeiouAEIOU'
Split=Input_str.split()
print(Split)
for w in Split:
    cnt=1
    for c in w:
        if c in v:
            cnt=cnt+1
            break
    if cnt >= n_cnt:
        n_cnt=cnt
        output=w
        print(output)
```

also you said in your question that cnt should be assigned to n_cnt but in your codes you did it incorrectly. The above source code will skip zzzz and print the other words in each line.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your motive is with this program but I assume you want to count the number of vowels in a particular string:

So, here is my implementation:

```
string = "I love Programming in Python"
vowel_cnt = 0
for i in string:
    if i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        vowel_cnt += 1
print("number  of vowels = ", vowel_cnt)
```

First, you initialize a counter to 0, then you iterate through all the indices of the string one by one and check if the element at that index is in the String with all the vowels i.e "aeiouAEIOU", if yes, you increment the counter by 1.